# ChartJS tooltip position / placement

Tags: javascript, position, tooltip, chart.js

When I hover on point of my line chart I can see tooltip. Unfortunatelly the tooltip position is left or right by default. This is how it looks now ->
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCZAx.png). And this is how I would like it to be -> [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjEIZ.png)

How can I change its position to top / bottom? any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you still need help with this.
Add the following option:

```
 options: {
    tooltips: {
        yAlign: 'top'
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick note for anyone else. This no-longer works

Answer (score 1):

In Chartjs v3, this works:

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            yAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    }
}
```